# Is it secure to save a .csv file in the plugins folder (or elsewhere)?

Tags: wordpress, security, wordpress-plugin-creation

I am building a plugin where I am currently saving a .csv file in the plugin folder (wp-content/plugins/plugin-name/file.csv) for the purpose of using it as as input for another web application.

However, I am not sure about the security of this. Obviously, anyone with a direct link can access the file. But is it being indexes by Google and can potentially end up being shown in a search? Can I somehow password protect the file and enable a web application to read the file using an username and a password?

Comment: I guess you're looking for `htaccess`

Comment: Thanks for your reply! But it really doesn't help me a lot. Can you please elaborate?

Comment: What he means is that you can use a ``.htaccess`` file to block users from accessing the file at a global level while still allowing it to be accessed internally on to applications on the server.